# Formula for CurrentDate with Set Time interval

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2010

I have a requirement to pass a parameter that calls the CurrentDate for a fixed time of day. Example:

StartDate = CurrentDate, at 8:00 am
End Date = CurrentDate, as 5:00 pm

Any suggestions on how this can be done would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't time to do anything in-depth but my first thought is to manipulate DateTime2FromParts

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213312.aspx

You can get the parts of the date using

select DATEPART(dd,  getdate())
... or replace dd with mm for month and so on.

Hope that helps